# Deploying node.js on Appfog?

Tags: hosting, web-hosting, deployment, node.js

I am developing an online chat application in HTML, CSS and JavaScript. I am using node.js and socket.io to make it work.

I recently realized that I need to host my app on a server. Fortunately I found appFog which is free. I created a account and created a new node.js app. It looks like this:

[image: appfog node.js app]

Now this is where I am confused.

- Why is there a domain name for my app. Do I use this domain name instead of `127.0.0.1`? I currently use 127.0.0.1 as I am testing my node.js in local environment.
- Say I want to deploy my app at my own webhost (which is 000webhost). Is that possible? Or do I need to use domain given by appFog?
- Are there any tutorials that explain how to deploy a node.js application on appFog? (for newbs like me)

Comment: Hey hi there if you want to deploy your node.js app on a free hosting then there is only two options for you(which are best for you rather than others) one is [heroku](https://www.heroku.com/) and the other is [alibaba](https://us.alibabacloud.com/en) cloud which gives which you can use for 1 year free(i.e, free trial) by signing up with your paytm account and you get a free VPS with alibaba cloud for more information visit [here](https://technologyundefined.blogspot.com/2021/04/deploy-your-node-app-in-000webhost-node-js-and-can-we.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you host your site on AppFog (Free plan), it will ask a subdomain name. Then you will get a subdomain like testnow.ap01.aws.af.cm. Here 'testnow' is the subdomain.

To set your custom domain, you need to to migrate to paid plan.

There are good tutorial in their website

Answer (score 0):

127.0.0.1 or localhost is your local machine.

So if you want to deploy your app to another server either appFog or another server, you can't access your deployed app this way.

I don't know if the free AppFog version does allow you to use your own domain like www.mydomain.com

Comment: thanks for the answer. i will do some research and notify what I found.